# shell:install gawk on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: bash, shell, unix, apt-get

i try to install gawk on Ubuntu 12.04 but it give an error

when i enter

```
sudo apt-get install gawk
```

it give me the following error.

```
E:unable to locate packet gawk.
```

Comment: Are you sure you typed `gawk` and not `gawk.`? The package is in the repos: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/gawk

Comment: `sudo apt-get install gawk.` uses a regex! You'd even get the docs!

Comment: Try http://askubuntu.com/questions/244268/installing-gawk-4-0-on-ubuntu-12-04.

Comment: please help????i type gawk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check, if the package's name is really `gawk`.
You can search for the package using:

```
apt-cache search gawk
```